# Properly timestamp a log file created by batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, timestamp

I am trying to create a log file with timestamps of events that are taking place in a batch file.

As you can see from the code below, I am not an expert when it comes to writing a batch file. The process works as it should, although the technique is very poor. In order to keep the batch file from deleting itself, I set it to read-only. I'll get around to figuring out how to exclude the batch file at some point. Right now that isn't as important.

```
@echo off
echo Compressing Files...
echo Compression Batch File STARTED: %date% %time% >> c:\temp\backup-compress.log
echo --------------------------------------------- >> c:\temp\backup-compress.log
for %%X in (*) do ( 
    "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tgzip "%%X.gz" "%%X"
    echo %%X Compressed: %date% %time:~-11,8% >> c:\temp\backup-compress.log
    echo Deleting: %%X
    del "%%X"
    echo %%X Deleted: %date% %time:~-11,8% >> c:\temp\backup-compress.log
    )
echo Moving compressed copies to Compressed Backups folder...
move *.gz "Compressed Backups\" > NUL
echo --------------------------------------------- >> c:\temp\backup-compress.log
echo Compression Batch File FINSHED: %date% %time% >> c:\temp\backup-compress.log
echo Compression completed successfully...
echo
```

The resulting log file looks exactly how I want it to, however, the time stamp and date remain constant throughout the log. Rather than an updated time stamp as events occur in the batch file, I only see the time and date that the batch file was started in place of every %time% and %date% instance.

**How can I correct this problem and see the right time and date stamps for the log file that I am creating?**

PS: Forgive me for the length of this post and what is likely a simple problem to solve. Also, if the tags are not quite right, I apologize, this is my first time actually posting a question, although the site has always been a great resource for answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `cmd` expands variables when a statement is *parsed* not directly prior to execution. A statement in this case is the complete `for` including the block after it. So all that remains within the `for` loop are literal strings, no variables.

You can use delayed expansion to correct the issue. Put the following at the start of your batch:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

and then use `!date!` and `!time!` within the loop. This will expand the variables just prior to executing a statement and thus will work as intended.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I have to admit that I saw this in some of my search results, however I didn't know that in order for !date! to work, I had to have the setlocal enabledelayedexpansion line. I tried it before and printed !date! and !time! all over the log file. 

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I use a little different method for getting proper times, because I don't care about the miliseconds.

I set my time like this:

```
FOR /F %%A IN ('TIME/T') DO SET timeEdit=%%A
ECHO %timeEdit%
```

This way I get the time the way I want it, the only downfall is that this is a bit longer than the setlocal method. You would need both lines if you wanted to capture multiple times, because you are hard-setting a variable for the Time, not capturing the time from the system in realtime.