# Folder with date format in mmddyyyy needed to be created using a bat file

Tags: file, batch-file

I want to create a batch file which when clicked will create a folder with the name 12012016.

I tried with the command

```
mkdir "E:\Meru\Work\Trace Reports\%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%
```

But its creates with the name 20160112.

Please help

Comment: What about rearranging the `%date%` parts to your needs -- ever had that idea?

Answer (score 0):

This question implies that you have not tried to understand what is going on with this command...

Split in part: `mkdir` will create a directory with the name you have given.

The name you have given is build together using a fixxed string, you decided to use `E:\Meru\Work\Trace Reports\` and three substrings from the system variable `%date%`.

Substring in batch works like this: `%variable_name:~last character NOT to use,number of characters you need%`. In your case it takes the year first, then the month and at last the day. You would just simply change the parts from `%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%` to `%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%%date:~6,4%`.

#### Notice!

The variable `%date%` has a different value based on the system settings for the time format. An alternative is the command `wmic os get localdatetime` which I covered in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39696448/6707985) that will always have the same output format no matter what the settings are.

Comment: can you share me the code to get the name as 20160112 with wmic os get localdatetime ?

Comment: No I will not! This is no free code writing service and it will not harm if you put a bit of brain into that yourself... I gave you a link to another answer where the usage of the above command is explained and I gave an explanation of how to get substrings. If you would put a little bit of effort into this, you can be done in around 15 minutes. As I see you are around with 0 badges so you have no even read the [tour page] to have a look on how this site works!

Comment: I am sorry but i dont see a substring command. Not sure functions of & and % signs in dos.

Comment: "`Substring in batch works like this: %variable_name:~last character NOT to use,number of characters you need%`." It is in my answer... Start of the 4th paragraph. `%` work as a variable sign basically -> `variable` is a string and `%variable%` is a variable. I do not know why you do need `&` now. Another thing: This is NOT DOS! A lot of people seem to be misunderstanding this. DOS means older operating systems like MS-DOS. This is either cmd.exe or batch whatever you want to call it...

Answer (score 0):

If you have read this ==> [Windows batch file redirect output to logfile with date/time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073197/windows-batch-file-redirect-output-to-logfile-with-date-time/31073743#31073743)

You can be able to do like this one :

```bat
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set datestamp=%dt:~0,8%
set timestamp=%dt:~8,6%
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%
set stamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%
echo stamp: "%stamp%"
pause
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
pause
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
pause
set MyDateVar=%MM%%DD%%YYYY%
echo My desired Variable Date to use is : %MyDateVar%
pause
mkdir "E:\Meru\Work\Trace Reports\%MyDateVar%"
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Because several hours have now elapsed:

```dos
mkdir "E:\Meru\Work\Trace Reports\%date:~0,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~6,4%"
```